# How to correctly specify a subquery in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets

there is such a query

```
=query(C13:D18;"select C, count(C) group by C")
```

[image]

how to output the third column, which will count the number of zeros in column B?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming that your original `QUERY` meant to reference `A13:B18`, since your post shows the raw data with "A" and "B" above. If that is true, then this should produce the result you want (written for the Russian locale):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A13:A18\COUNTIFS(A13:A18;A13:A18;B13:B18;0)};"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1), MAX(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 Label COUNT(Col1) '', MAX(Col2) ''"))`

If you did mean `C13:D18`, simply change the relative references in the formula accordingly.

The `QUERY` here is acting on a virtual array, which is contained between curly brackets {}. The second column of that array is a `COUNTIFS` for each unique value in Column A, counting only those where Column B is equal to 0.

The `QUERY` returns the MAX of those results, which will be the total number of zeroes per unique value in Column A (since the only two results will be either 0 for all or max for all).

I also added `LABEL` into the `QUERY` to get rid of the top headers in the `QUERY` results.